# Where in the Twanging Gardens can I find ginger?

Tags: kynseed

I am looking for ginger, which [is reported](https://steamcommunity.com/app/758870/discussions/0/3723946017824498331/) to be located in the [Twanging Gardens](https://kynseed.fandom.com/wiki/The_Twanging_Gardens?file=TwangingGardens.png). But I can't find it. Where *exactly* is it located?